# Representing multiple attributes for students

Tags: database-design

I have a data structure that has group of students.
Each student has an array of attributes - that is, he has an array of strings that represent attributes

How do I plan my data structure? Have a table of students and another table of classes in each grade has a pointer to his students

I need to save all to database - on android device.

Or something else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have a Student Table which is a parent table. These represent single line attributes, which can all fit in this one table. 
If you need any data, where a student may have multiple attributes (example signing up for many classes, or different address types), to avoid multiple rows and data redundancy, I would create child tables.

**Parent Table:**

> *`create table dbo.Student
>   (
>       StudentId int identity(1,1) primary key,
>       FirstName varchar(55) not null,
>       LastName varchar(55) not null
>   )*`

**Child Tables**:

> *`create table dbo.CourseCatalog
>   (
>       CourseCatalogId int identity(1,1) primary key,
>       ClassName varchar(55) not null,
>       CourseStartDate date not null,
>       CouseEndDate date not null
>   )*`
>
> *`create table dbo.StudentEnrollment
>   (
>       StudentEnrollmentId int identity(1,1) not null primary key,
>       CourseCatalogId int not null foreign key references CourseCatalog(CourseCatalogId),
>       StudentId int not null foreign key references Student(StudentId),
>   )*`
>
> *`create table dbo.AddressType
>   (
>       AddressTypeId int identity(1,1) not null primary key,
>       AddressType varchar(55) not null    -- Example 1 is Home, 2 is Campus Address
>   )*`
>
> *`create table dbo.StudentAddress
>   (
>       StudentAddressId int not null primary key,
>       StudentId int not null foreign key references Student(StudentId),
>       AddressType int not null foreign key references AddressType(AddressTypeId)
>   )*`

by the way, can someone edit to properly remove asterisks, also feel free to add to this as needed

Comment: thanks, but there is something i can't understand - ( this is my first time i doing some database .. ) each student learn more then one course - so how to save for each student the list of the courses that he learn ?

Comment: please use the table dbo.StudentEnrollment, shows course catalog and studentid